# ImageField default upload_to directory changes

Tags: django, django-models

When I upload an image, it doesn't get saved to default `upload_to` directory (`get_news_image`). Instead it created a new directory (`new`) that has the name of the Model (`News`) and each image I add uploads there.

I'm using class based views, are they automatically making an upload folder for my images??

[image]

On the left side in the bottom you can see my media folder:

[image]

Comment: where is your get_news_image, can you update the question with it?

Comment: If you mean the folder, it's right in the media, you can see it on the left bottom of the uploaded images. As you can see, the folder is open, but there are no files inside.

Comment: the function, not the folder

Comment: Yeah, turns out that was the issue. I thought that get_news_image is just a directory, turns out it's a function that returns news. Thank you!